Audrey Hepburn enters the suite of a business tycoon and says she's "leaving"
I'm trying to find a movie starring Audrey Hepburn. I could only watch a bit, and it was somewhat like this:
Audrey Hepburn enters the suite of a business tycoon, and says she's "leaving". The man insists that she stays (to eat, drink something, can't remember). She doesn't seem to be interested but then dances with him, amongst other stuff. The man records memos in a machine, about meetings, projects and other stuff, while leaning back and enjoying a smoke or drink or something of the sort. Then one can see the man listening to Hepburn's recordings saying silly stuff, maybe like "A monkey in a suit with a golden banana." or whatever. The man laughs calmly and enjoys listening.

Could it be Love in the Afternoon with Gary Cooper? He plays a business tycoon, and in this clip (which is not the scene you are looking for), he is playing with a dictaphone.

I've just looked at Love in the Afternoon and it's definitely the right one.  (The recording is of Hepburn listing the "men in her life":  "Item 18: an Italian vice-consul.  Item 19: a Dutch alcoholic.")
